# Как пишутся игровые сервера?

Tags: gameserver, c++

Хотелось бы наити книги статьи по данному предмету. Можно на английском(если конечно русских аналогов нету)

Comment: они пишутся так: "игровые серверы"

Comment: Я думаю что у каждого свой подход и ничего конкретного ты не найдешь.

Comment: http://ggs-kandidat.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Если есть возможность, то используют готовые, например: [RedDwarf Server](http://www.reddwarfserver.org/?q=content/open-source-online-gaming-universe)
2. Иначе делают самостоятельно. [Особенной](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80) специфики в игровых серверах нет.

Comment: Ваша первая ссылка, кажется, не работает, вернее она ведет совсем не туда, куда предполагается.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.trinitycore.org/w/Main_Page
http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/MaNGOS

Вот можешь посмотреть на примере эмуляторов World Of Warcraft.

Answer (score 0):

Есть эмуль RO.
Это форум http://eathena.ws .

Answer (score 0):

Да можешь найти любую Java сборку серва Lineage II и посмотреть её